# Determine read or write query neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

Given a string containing a Neo4j cypher query, how to determine ***quickly*** in python it is db read or db write.

Currently I have thought of two ways of seeing this -

1. Check for keywords like **CREATE, DELETE** etc to tag write queries 
   and
   **MATCH, START** etc to tag read queries.
2. Otherwise we can check for patterns according to this link here- [Neo4j refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) and write a parser for it accordingly.

Method 1 fails here -

```
MATCH (n:Person {id:1, create:3}) return n
```

And method 2 looks too deep for seemingly small task.

Any other/better ideas to do the same?

Comment: You can modify method 1 to check if the keyword is outside any brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`EXPLAIN`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#how-do-i-profile-a-query) option and inspect `operatorType` of the execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN MERGE (n:Person)
```

and find and check for possible values for writing, updating and other, something like that

```
"operatorType": "MergeCreateNode"
"operatorType": "CreateNode"
"operatorType": "MergeCreateRelationship"
```

Comment: You were right. Giving explain option in queries through REST api gave me enough info to determine query type. Thanks a lot!!